# Can we send Splunk alerts to private Mattermost channel

Tags: alert, splunk, mattermost

I have Splunk alerts working and they send alerts to a public channel. However I want to send alerts to a private channel. Is there a token setting or some configuration that I have to take care as I don't see alerts coming in to the private channel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ofcourse

Install [HTTP Alert Action](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/5022) app and there you can send a custom API request as a alert trigger.

There use mattermost api request to send the message to mattermost.

https://developers.mattermost.com/integrate/webhooks/incoming/